# A comparative analysis of Scrivener 2 and iBook Author

Tags: tools, scrivener

I have been using [iBook Author](http://www.apple.com/in/ibooks-author/) for a long time now, and recently, from [this answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/27/2088), I came to know about [Scrivener2](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php). Which, from it's webpage and advertisement looks to me like a good tool.

Have anyone use both of these before and can help me to make the decision, whether I should change my tool or not?

Comment: I'm not familiar with iBook Author, but from the website it looks like a tool which allows you to write and then helps you format ebooks. Scrivener is a top-notch *word processor*, meant to allow you to write and plan. It's not a formatter. So they're apples and oranges.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather from the website, iBooks Author is a Mac-specific eBook creation tool. It uses drag and drop functionality to help create eBooks for Mac and iPad. Looks cool, actually, but I'm not a Mac user, so I can't say.

On the other hand (and as KeithS already stated in his comment), Scrivener is a multi-purpose tool, which allows you to organize, write, and print or export your manuscript from scratch. It's capable of many things writers find useful during the creation process, and when that phase is completed, it has the ability to compile the manuscript into many different formats, for many different purposes, ebooks included.

I would disagree with the "word processor" assessment KeithS gave Scrivener (I'd describe it as a "writer's tool" personally, since it does so much more than the word processing aspect), but his analysis is accurate. They're really not the same type of tool.