# Do vampire hybrids inherit powers from male vampires?

Tags: fantasy, planning

I have looked at the half-human-half-vampires a.k.a Dhampirs in the Wikipedia section to find that most of them had mortal mothers and vampire fathers. In history records in Serbia it was said that Serbian women were impregnanted by 'Vampires'

But what if a mortal human male knocked up a vampiress, would that still be the same result, in spite of the genders being reversed?

Comment: This would be better placed in Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers SE! Vampirism have different rules (different powers, weaknesses, personalities, etc.) in every vampire story ever written or told. There is no true truth about vampires, because they have never existed IRL. If you want to ask a question about a specific kind of vampires (Bram Stocker's vampires, Twillight vampires, True Blood vampires, etc.), you should say it in your question. But anyway, it would not be on scope on this site. Try asking it on [Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) (don't forget to mention a specific franchise in your question).

Comment: HI Edmund, and welcome to Writers SE. This site is about writing, not *what to write*. There are other SE sites that would be better suited for those questions. Please only use this site for questions *about* writing, *how* to write, and the like.

Comment: Hi Thomas, but what is the difference?

Comment: @EdmundFrost On [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) you can ask questions to help you build your fictionnal world like [How could dragons be explained without magic?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=fantasy), on Writers, you can ask questions on how to write like [Is there a special software for writers?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9/is-there-a-special-software-for-writers). If you have questions on existing fantasy franchises (books, movies or comics) you can ask them on [Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vampires are fictional. You make up their characteristics. Vampires, in fiction, have evolvled over time. Try reading Bram Stocker's *Dracula* so you can see what the original was.

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about writing fiction is that generally you can make it whatever you want. As others have stated, a lot of vampires in fiction are completely different from each other. One of the most successful vampire fiction franchises breaks pretty much all of the old school rules. If you don't like Twilight vampires that's okay. I was just using them as an example of breaking traditional folklore.

Comment: Ha. I thought you were referring to _Interview with the Vampire._